# SMTP email does not work even with the right firewall rules

Tags: plugins, errors, email, smtp

I am using Mailer Send as my SMTP service and the Fluent SMTP plugin. But it does not matter the plugin with every SMTP plugin I get this error.
When I try to send emails, I always get this error:

```
{
  "code": 423,
  "message": "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server",
  "errors": [
    "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server"
  ]
}
```

I have port 587 open in my firewall and my hosting provider allows email to be sent through this port.
What can I do to solve this problem?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: are you _sure_ your server is set up correctly? I don't believe this is a WordPress problem, but rather a general host problem. You would be better trying to send it directly via SSH/CLI on the host itself to confirm that a connection is actually possible, or even from your local computer. Likewise you mentioned port `587` is open on your server, but is it open on the SMTP server you're trying to connect it to?  You should get in touch with your host

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. Mailer Send is a paid service, they are set up correctly and my server firewall is cofigured with the outgoing rule: Any IPv4, Any IPv6 TCP 587, so it should work. I wrote to the SMTP provider and my VPS host and both denied that it was a problem on their part.

Comment: Is there any way I can get more information about the error so I can better understand where it is coming from?

Comment: I think the error already has as much information as it could provide, it tried to make a connection to the server and failed, so no SMTP stuff had a chance to take place. Think of it like trying to talk to someone and being unable to find them, and I ask you what you said that made the conversation go badly, you can't debug SMTP if basic network connectivity prevents a connection. Note that you could plug your SMTP details into an email client and attempt to send an email and that too would be informative. Fundamentally though the chances this is WP related are very very low

Comment: When I try it on an email client it works.

Comment: and have you contacted your host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following test.

1. Disable all of your SMTP plugins.
2. Temporarily enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in your "wp-config.php" file.
3. Insert the following code in your theme "functions.php" file:

```php
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function ( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Port       = 587;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $phpmailer->FromName   = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Type your SMTP credentials below.
    $phpmailer->From = ''; // This is the email address that will be used as sender.
    $phpmailer->Host = '';
    $phpmailer->Username = '';
    $phpmailer->Password = '';

    // Temporarily enable while debugging.
    $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

4. Type your credentials in the snippet above and try to send an email. For example, try to reset your password.
5. Did the message reach your inbox?
6. If not, what's inside the file "debug.log" (".../wp-content/debug.log")?

Comment: Yes, I got the message but it took about 5 minutes to get to my inbox. It is not marked as spam, so it must have used the SMTP server. Or maybe not, because I see no use in my SMTP server dashboard, the credentials have not been used.
What should I do now? 
Also just a note in my debug.og file ther is always this line: [26-Jul-2023 20:58:55 UTC] PHP Deprecated:

Comment: Never mind, my dashboard was broken, it was using SMTP to send. But what should I do now WordPress emails are still not beeing sent (iThemes Security emails and ....)?

Comment: @AYNTK so the reset password email was sent, but other emails are not being sent? And what's you php version and wp version?

Comment: Yes exactely. PHP 8.2 and WordPress 6.2.2

Comment: @AYNTK In this case an issue with SMTP connection is ruled out. I suggest you visit the article https://help.ithemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050104153-Emails-Not-Being-Sent and thoroughly go through each item. It might solve your problem. LMK how that goes.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, I'm suddenly getting some emails. Your code snippet and SMPT seems to work (3 emails were sent via SMTP). But why does your code work and when I try a plugin it does not work? So a plugin with the same SMTP details always gave me the error you can see in my first message, now with your code in functions.php it seems to work. But why does it not work with a plugin (Fluent SMPT or the official mailer send one), both did not work. How can I find out why it works now? And why does it not work with a plugin?

Comment: And also not all emails are being sent a few still fail! According to the log.

Comment: @AYNTK So you installed the plugin to keep a record of all emails sent? This is cool and recommended to make sure you don't miss anything. From where I'm standing it's hard to say why a plugin doesn't work properly. If you really want the sending to be handled by a plugin, I suggest you use WP Mail Smtp and SendLayer. They're both maintained by the same company and might solve the problem. LMK how that goes.

Comment: I will try. But why does it work with the code? and can I just leave it like this and use your code to send emails? Is this a secure option or is a Plugin more secure (or storing the Password in the config file)? Also when I remove the code sometimes it works with the plugin (Fluent SMTP) and sometimes it does not why?

Comment: @AYNTK The code works basically because it's a raw snippet with no conditions etc. At the end any SMTP plugin actually does what my code does, but with a lot of other code layers behind it. As long as you''re the only one who can access your server files your password is secure. I personally don't use any plugins, I built that small code for personal use. Depending on how your business works, sometimes you might want a different "From". That snippet makes the "From" always the same, which works for me. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I have also tried other SMTP servers and some are faster than my current one. Also I do not know why SMPT via a plugin just works now, no idea why I did not change anything. Is the snippet safe? and why is it stored in the theme and not in the wp-config.php file?
Thank you very much for your help and time and the snippet.

Comment: @AYNTK Actually, the snippet should be a plugin. It's not supposed to go in the functions.php though it works there. Are you familiar with the mu-plugins folder? Just create a file with that code inside the folder wp-content/mu-plugins. For example: "wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-smtp-config.php". Also, keep the plugin which stores all the emails sent, I believe it's a good call. And, yes, the code has no security issues.

Comment: @AYNTK BTW remove/comment the line that enables the debug mode.

Comment: I will do that, I think I also found a problem regarding my SMPT provider there connection always times out while sending. So maybe that was the problem after all.
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, time and the code snippet.